# How to get data from FormData Javascript send in C#

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api, form-data

## My code int Client:

```
var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("ID", "1");
        formData.append("Name", "Gà Haha");
        console.log(formData.get("ID"));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:13497/myapi/student",
            contentType: "json",//Request header
            data:formData,
            dataType: "json",//Responce header
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, value)
                {
                    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(value);
                    var objData = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
                    var id = objData.ID;
                    var fname = objData.Name;
                    var lname = objData.Price;
                    $('<tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + fname + '</td><td>' + lname + '</td></tr>').appendTo('#students');
                });
            },
            error: function (errormsg) {
                alert(errormsg.responseText);
            }
        });
```

## My code in server:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<Products> GetStudents()
    {
        string temp=HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["ID"];
        return temp;
    }
```

But *temp* return null. I'm using [How can retrieve string formData js in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099078/how-can-retrieve-string-formdata-js-in-c-sharp) but return empty and here [How to read FormData into Web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40798148/how-to-read-formdata-into-web-api/43043555) but it not working.

> Finally: I want to get data from FormData Client send

Comment: try to hide `contentType: "json",` and `dataType: "json",` from your ajax call and let me know

Comment: Tried! But It not working

Comment: your ajax url contains `student` but there is no any api exist with this name. if you want to hit `GetStudents` then replace `student` with `GetStudents` in url

Comment: I'm found my error. Maybe cause is URL Friendly, So, I'm comment URL Friendly. But Im unknown call back my function. Please help me

Comment: First you should fix your request and ensure it's send as form data with correct headers. You can read about that e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery and check it using your browsers developer tools.

Comment: Root folder. <https://imgur.com/a/fbTvvJk> Please help me call back my function

Comment: in network tab of browser watch your ajax call properly sent posted data to api. And also check once your url is pointed to desired api i.e. `GetStudents`

Answer (score 0):

Please try in server side

Use form

HttpContext.Current.Request.**Form**["ID"] instead of Request.**Params**["ID"]